# How to pass an object to another activity? If the object already implements an interface (so it can't implement Parcelable)?

Tags: android, parcelable, serializable

I'm trying to pass an Object from one activity to another and I know I should use `Parcelable` or `Serializable` but my Object class implements an interface already. Is there any way around this?

Comment: An object cannot extend more than one class but can implement many interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects can implement multiple interfaces:

```
class MyClass implements Interface1, Parcelable {
  // Implement each interface
}
```

Comment: Wow I knew that. Sorry, Thank you very much! I'll mark your answer as correct once I can.

Answer (score 2):

I think the right thing is just to use Intent.putExtras() - where you can pass primitive data types + objects of type String, Bundle, Parcelable, Serializable. You are simply using key/value pairs. And after that you can get your data by Intent.getExtras(). Everything is quite simple. Also have a look at this links, they are for bigginers, but really helpful: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html and http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html. If the problem is somewhere deeper - please describe it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure! A class can implement multiple interfaces. You'll just need to separate each one with a comma in your class declaration, like this...

```
public class YourClass implements interface1, interface2, interface3 { 
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An object cannot extend more than one class but can implement many interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
Parcelable and `Serializable` are the way but little complex. an easy solution is just use `Gson` or any other JSON library..
```

in first activity.

```
String objJson = new Gson().toJson(object);
intent.putExtra("key",objJson);
```

and in your second activity

```
YourClass yourClass = new Gson().fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("key"),YourClass.class) ;
```

for Gson library check this link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm